# Help with PHP regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to replace all the letters and spaces after the first two, using PHP's preg_replace.  Here is my failed attempt at doing so:

```
echo preg_replace('/^[a-zA-Z]{2}([a-zA-Z ])*.*$/i','','FALL 2012'); //expected output is "FA2012", but it outputs nothing
```

I'm just trying to replace the part in parentheses `([a-zA-Z ])` .. I'm guessing I'm not doing it right to just replace that part..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking it to replace the entire string. Use a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match the first two characters instead.

```
echo preg_replace('/(?<=^[a-z]{2})[a-z ]*/i','','FALL 2012');
```

By the way, the `i` modifier means it's case insensitive, so you don't need to match both uppercase and lowercase characters.

Comment: I think you have the preg_match/preg_replace backwards. preg_replace uses grouping in the replacement. $1 is the first group, $2 is the second...and so on.

Comment: This expression has a typo (?< instead of ?<=) and it won't match anything since there can be no characters before the start of the subject (^ needs to be include in the lookbehind).

Comment: @Jonathan: You're right. Not enough coffee, clearly. Deleted that part of my answer.

Comment: @jaytea: Apologies. I didn't have access to a PHP environment when I was writing this. I've edited my answer to suit. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

The `/i` at the end makes it case-insensitive.  The `(?<=regex)` means look immediately before the current position for the beginning of the line followed by 2 letters.

```
echo preg_replace('/(?<=^[a-z]{2})[a-z ]*/i','','FALL 2012');
```

Answer (score 0):

you are saying to replace the entire match with blank (''). You want to put the parenthesis around the parts you want to keep and then replace with $1$2 which is equal to what is in the first (`$1`) and second (`$2`) set of parenthesis.

```
preg_replace("/^([a-z]{2})[a-z\s]*(.*)$/i", '$1$2', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can get away with a `(?<=lookbehind)`; however, in certain other cases you may find the \K escape to be more suitable. What it does is reset the start offset value passed by the application to the current position in the subject, effectively dumping the portion of the string that was consumed thus far in the current match. For example:

```
preg_replace('^[a-z]{2}\K[a-z ]*/i', '', 'FALL 2012')
```

Now only the substring matched by `[a-z ]*` is substituted.